# Compact embedding of ${\rm L}^1_{loc}$ space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, compactness, embeddings

I was reading one preprint and stumbled upon a part in the proof where one particular embedding was used. Namely:

> Let $\Omega\subset{\bf R}^2$ be open and bounded and let $p\in\langle
> 1,2\rangle$. Then ${\rm L}^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded into
>   ${\rm W}^{-1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$.

Since I never saw ${\rm L}^1_{loc}$ being embedded into anything "useful", I have decided to check it. My only, and so far unsuccessful, attempt was to use a version of Schauder's theorem for locally convex topological vector spaces (it can be found, for example, in Grothendieck's book "Topological Vector Spaces"), but since ${\rm L}^1_{loc}$ and ${\rm L}^\infty_c$ are not reflexive, it got me nowhere.

Does anyone have any idea why this embedding would be valid?

Preprint with the claim: [click here](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~gqchen/preprints/cpmthd/update.pdf) (one sentence before formula (2.23))

Comment: How do you define "boundedness" in $L_{loc}^1$, which *a priori* doesn't have a norm on it?

Comment: If it were normed, I could just use the standard Schauder's theorem. ${\rm L}^1_{loc}$ is complete metrizable locally convex space (the topology is generated by a countable family of seminorms). So, to say that a set is bounded it is to say that it is bounded with respect to all continuous seminorms.

Comment: Then could you just use a sequence of mollifiers exhausting $\Omega$ and the diagonalization argument?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: If, as usual, $L^1_{loc}$ is the spaces of (equivalence classes of) measurable functions $f$ with $\int_k |f| <\infty$ for all compact sets $K$, it is not clear to me what compactness means. As Semmel comments, it is a (complete metrizable) locally convex space and in that category there are two candidates for a definition: Either a $0$-neighborhood is mapped to a relatively compact set (this is a *very strong* requirement) or all bounded sets are mapped to relatively compact ones (I know the name Montel-operator for the latter case).

Comment: In the paper appear expressions like $\|f\|_{L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^2)}$ which make no sense for the space of locally integrable functions.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but I believe that the author was a bit careless about the notation. I think he actually meant to say that "up to the multiplication with an arbitrary smooth function" where he would have spaces ${\rm L}^1(\Omega)$ and ${\rm W}^{-1,p}(\Omega)$. It is the only explanation I have managed to come up with and if I go through the proof with it, it works.